# MS Access 2013: Top 10 Items sold in each country

Tags: ms-access-2013

I need write a query to get top 10 Items sold in each country

**Database Type is MS Access 2013**

Table Name: SoldItems
Fields
Country
Item

Query

This query will get me all items sold in each country ordered descending by count of sold items in each country, i only need top 10 items sold in each country

SELECT   count(*) As CountOfItemsSold, Country, Item
from SoldItems
group by Country,  Item

order by  2,1 desc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select top N rows for each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700550/select-top-n-rows-for-each-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a sub query that returns the Top 10 items grouped by country and use that as the basis for a filter. Something like:

```
SELECT S.Country, S.Item, COUNT(S.Item) AS CountOfItem
FROM SoldItems AS S
GROUP BY S.Country, S.Item
HAVING S.Item In (SELECT TOP 10 R.Item
    FROM SoldItems AS R
    GROUP BY R.Country, R.Item
    HAVING R.Country=S.Country
    ORDER BY COUNT(R.Item) DESC
)
ORDER BY S.Country, COUNT(S.Item) DESC;
```

Note that if there are items with an equal number of items sold, then you will get more than 10 records returned per country.

Regards,

Comment: Please re-read the last paragraph of my answer. If the records in 9th, 10th and 11th place for a country all have the same count, then all three records will be returned, giving 11 records returned for that country. Access has no way of differentiating between these 3 items.

Comment: I checked the data again, you are correct, it is working fine