# Getting just the rows with smallest date and qty

Tags: sql

I am new on Sql, I need to get the rows in yellow from the table blow

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJgeK.png)

I try the group by concept :

```
Select code , Min(date), SUM(qty)
from table 
group by Trabsact_date , code
```

but seems not working and i am not sure about the SUM i used ?

Any help Thank you!

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT - except those who are arguments to aggregate functions. I.e. try `group by code`.

Comment: BTW, most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, i.e. no images, no links.

Comment: Also add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: SQL is a language, not a database. Add tag for database you use. You want oldest date record for each transect date? Returning entire record requires a subquery. Database used can dictate syntax.

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39700550/select-top-n-rows-for-each-group and http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#TopN

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Top N per group

Answer (score 0):

As you're a new community member, there's no previous history which would reveal which database you might be using.

Anyway, to get you started: nowadays, we usually do it with a help of analytic functions, such as `row_number` or `rank` and a subquery (or a CTE, common table expression): first "sort" rows in source tables by date in ascending order, partitioned by `code` and `transact_date`. Then - in *main* query - fetch rows that ranked as the highest.

```
with temp as
  (select t.*,
     row_number() over (partition by code, transact_date order by date asc) rn
   from your_table t
  )
select code, date, qty, transact_date
from temp
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct code line will be this

`SELECT Code, MIN(Date) AS Min_date, SUM(Qty) AS Total_quantity FROM table GROUP BY Code;`